# Def take() in my program

Tags: python

```
 def take(self, add_item):
        if self.__items < 8:
            self.__items.pop(add_item)
        else:
            print("You already have the max items in your inventory,sorry")
```

This is the only problem that I'm having with my program and I'm trying to figure what exactly the problem is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python31\player.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python31\player.py", line 32, in main
    play.take(add_item)
  File "C:\Python31\player.py", line 66, in take
    if self.__items < 8:
TypeError: unorderable types: list() < int()
```

I'm trying to figure out why I keep getting this error message. I tried changing around the code and still got the same error message

Comment: DBB: If you have a new question, please post a new question. If one of the answers below have solved your question, please click the checkmark next to their answers.

Comment: i think you need to learn basic datastructure and how to use please go through python docs.then you would clearly understand what r u doing .learn difference between string and list

Comment: I know the difference between a string and a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to *add* the item `add_item` to the list, you are using the wrong function.  You should use `append(add_item)`, not `pop(add_item)`.

```
def take(self, add_item):
    if len(self.__items) < 8:
        self.__items.append(add_item)
    else:
        print("You already have the max items in your inventory,sorry")
```

[This Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) explains what the list methods do.  `pop` was expecting an integer argument, which led to the error you saw.  `pop` will remove one element from your list.

As others have already pointed out, you also need to check the *length* of the list in the same function, using `len(self.__items)`.

Comment: I had append before I changed it to pop. That's what our teacher showed us in class

Comment: Do you want the function to add to the list `self.__items`, or remove from that list?  It looks like you want to add to the list in the `take` function.

Comment: it's to add to the list. Now it works since I changed it back to append but it doesn't actually add anything to the list

Comment: @DBB use more `print` to see what's going on in code.

Answer (score 2):

your items is `list` you cannot comapare with `int`

i think your checking for length

give `if len(self.__items) < 8 :`

and one more thing in your program your sending string to the take method and performing pop()
i think its not posible.

i think you want to append it use `append(add_items)`

Comment: I did that now it says a 'str' item can't be returned as an integer

Comment: I posted my whole program

Comment: the problem is your sending a string into take and your comaping its list and doing pop() thats not coorect

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `len()` to get number of elements on list

```
if len(self.__items) < 8:
```

Comment: I did that now it says a 'str' item can't be returned as an integer

Comment: Show how you create `self.__items` - or maybe you have own function `len()`

Comment: And always show full error message - there is number of line with problem - show this line in code. Probably new problem is in new place.

Comment: I posted my whole program

Comment: Problem with `str` is new problem (and has nothing to do with previous one) so you should create new question. Beside someone delete full code :)

Comment: Yeah I don't have that problem anymore. I changed my code back to what I previously had it before